# ngModel not working in two different components?

Tags: angular, two-way-binding, ngmodel

The title is pretty self-explanatory, so - I put an input element in app.component.html file, this is the code:
`<input type="text" name="titleInput" id="titleInput" [(ngModel)]="titleInput">`
Then i tried making an h1 element in another component, as I wanted it to display what was typed in the input field. Didn't work. Made an h1 element in app.component - works fine. I searched a lot, but didn't find anything. Can you help me?

Comment: In your "other" component, are you using lazy loading?

Comment: are those component have parent child relationship ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your model `titleInput` which is manipulated through the `input` to display, in your case, in your header tag using interpolation, i.e. `{{.}}`.

For example:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{titleInput}}</h1>
    <input type="text" name="titleInput" id="titleInput" [(ngModel)]="titleInput"/>
</div>
```

You can see it working [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/eQK7gjWS2wIYJy5Bnm9z?p=preview).

Comment: In this example i can see it works, but it works in the same component. And i'm trying to use string interpolation, but the h1 element is in another component, and then it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

Either do it with a child parent relationship with `@Input`.
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction (see other post).

Or use `LocalStorage.setItem('titleInput', titleInput);` in first component.

And in second `LocalStorage.getItem('titleInput');` and `LocalStorage.removeItem('titleInput');`

Comment: Well, i should type "@Input() titleInput" in the other component's ts file, right?